# Guice: wiring a bean with complex creational pattern

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am using Guava to create an `EventBus` for a publish-subscribe messaging service. I am also attempting to use Guice for the first time. I've read the Guice tutorials, and have been playing around with the `AbstractModule` and `Binder` classes. But the minute I leave the tutorials and try to actually get something working for my project, I'm choking.

My project has an `EventMonitor` that will have a Guice-injected instance of the Guava `EventBus`:

```
public class EventMonitor {
    @Inject
    private EventBus guavaEventBus;

    // ...
}
```

In the Guice/DI/Bootstrapping code of my application, I define an `AbstractModule` concretion:

```
public class MyAppModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        // Here is where I want to wire together the EventBus to give
        // to the EventMonitor.
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I'd like an `EventBus` that would normally be constructed (in non-Guice code) like so:

```
ThreadFactory factory = ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();
Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(factory)
EventBus eventBus = new AsyncEventBus(executor);
```

I'm choking because of the two (seemingly un-injectable) static methods on `ThreadManager` and `Executors`, and because my reference is for an `EventBus` but the actual object is an `AsynEventBus`; thus I'm not sure how to bind it:

```
// Doesn't work because how does Guice know I'm referencing an AsyncEventBus?!?
bind(EventBus.class).toInstance(executor);

// Doesn't work because now I've lost the ability to pass the
// AsyncEventBus an 'executor' and no-arg ctor is used!
bind(EventBus.class).to(AsyncEventBus.class);
```

So I ask: given the manner in which I'd like to construct my `EventBus`, how would a battle-worn Guice veteran wire things up here (using the `ThreadFactory`, `Executor` and `EventBus`) such that in `EventMonitor`, the fully-configured `EventBus` is properly injected? I think once I see this more "complex" example, I'll start to see the forest through the trees. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how would a battle-worn Guice veteran wire things up here

Two words: Provider methods.

```
public class MyAppModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(EventBus.class).to(AsyncEventBus.class);
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    ThreadFactory providesThreadFactory() {
        return ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    Executor providesExecutor(ThreadFactory factory) {
        return Executors.newCachedThreadPool(factory)
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    AsyncEventBus providesAsyncEventBus(Executor executor) {
        return new AsyncEventBus(executor);
    }
}
```

The convention of naming an `@Provides` method beginning with "provides" isn't something guice needs, but is something you really want to do, especially on a large codebase. Being able to search through a body of code for "provides" and find the method that provides a particular object.

A few notes to answer questions in the comments:

- Guice examines every `Module` instance you install for `@Provides` methods, and installs them as though you'd bound the return type of the method with `.toProvider` to an anonymous `Provider` instance. So the great thing about them is that you don't need any additional code inside your `configure` method to get it to use them.
- The `@Singleton` annotation tells guice that you only want one instance of that thing, so it'll only call the `provides*` method once. The default, if you leave it off, is to have guice call your provider and/or instantiate a new object (depending on what you've configured for that class) every time it needs to inject an instance. Note: some people freak out when first discovering this, and then want to put `@Singleton` everywhere "for efficiency" - this is an improper reaction. In reality, you really want to use `@Singleton` sparingly and only where it would be incorrect to have multiple different instances.

  In this case, we want to make very certain that there's only one `EventBus` around. So long as you aren't directly injecting `Executor` or `ThreadFactory` into any other classes, you could leave the annotations off those methods. For `ThreadFactory` this almost certainly won't make a difference since I think `ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory()` returns the same instance each time it's called anyway. It would make a difference for `Executor`, but maybe you wanted a new `Executor` instance in other places where you're using it?
- The parameters to the `@Provides` methods are wired up the same way as the rest of the configuration. For example, in this case I know that `providesAsyncEventBus` will get the `Executor` that was returned by `providesExecutor` because that's the instance guice will inject whenever it's asked for an `Executor`. If I had two methods like this:

  ```
  @Provides @Singleton
  Executor providesExecutor1(ThreadFactory factory) {
      return Executors.newCachedThreadPool(factory)
  }

  @Provides @Singleton
  Executor providesExecutor2(ThreadFactory factory) {
      return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10, factory)
  }
  ```

  Then guice would throw a configuration error when you tried creating the injector, because you've told guice to use two different ways to get an `Executor`. Now, if instead I had something like this:

  ```
  @Provides @Singleton
  ExecutorService providesExecutor1(ThreadFactory factory) {
      return Executors.newCachedThreadPool(factory)
  }

  @Provides @Singleton
  ScheduledExecutorService providesExecutor2(ThreadFactory factory) {
      return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10, factory)
  }
  ```

  but still had the `providesAsyncEventBus` method as above, then guice would throw an error when you tried creating the injector because you didn't tell it how to create the `Executor` that `providesAsyncEventBus` requires. You'd need an additional line like:

  ```
  bind(Executor.class).to(ExecutorService.class);
  ```

  in your `configure` method to resolve the issue.
- As for your `register` methods, you have a few options. What I believe is by far the easiest way to go is to just add a `EventBus` parameter to the `@Inject`-annotated constructor of your objects that need to get registered and then do `evtBus.register(this)` as the last line of the constructor.

  Other options include using static injection (which you can read about, but I wouldn't recommend), or binding a `Set<Object>` with the appropriate annotation using multibinders and then in the same startup code where you create the `Injector`, iterate over that set to register anything. (This second method can be done in some nice patterns, but I wouldn't recommend it until you learn more about simpler guice usage patterns)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Martin (+1) - 3 quick followups: What's the rule of thumb with `@Singleton`? Should providers always provider `@Singleton`? What happens if I didn't specify it on all these providers? Second, the `EventBus` object has a `register(Object)` method on it, where I register all the different "event listeners". **Where do I make these `register` calls?** I assume that, if I want the same, singleton `EventBus` returned everytime I ask Guice for one, I'd have to make those calls from inside `providesAsyncEventBus`, yes? Thanks again!

Comment: Third, does Guice know to automatically wire the provider methods? For instance, `providesAsyncEventBus(Executor)` needs an `Executor`. Does Guice know to use the `providesExecutor` because of the `@Providers` annotation? Executor is subclassed by `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and `ThreadPoolExecutor`. What if you have two provider methods, 1 for each subclass? How would `providesAsyncEventBus(Executor)` know which provider method to call to obtain the `Executor`?

Comment: Updated answer to address these comments

Comment: I think it would be best to add a binding annotation to the provider method for `Executor` (or, more simply, create the `Executor` in the provider method for `AsyncEventBus`). You probably don't want anyone who injects an `Executor` to use the same thread pool as the event bus